# Use of vba to select from a dropdown in internet explorer from a table element -

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I need some help in getting my vba code to automate the login to a website and then on the page which loads to select an option from a dropdown menu. My code succesfully logs into the website, but it keeps returning an error at the 'selecting from the dropdown' part. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0LKY.jpg) to see the full code from the table element which shows the option I need to select towards the end of the html code labelled 'TPS Managed Balanced - Dec 11" which has a value = 303591430

See my code so far, note it breaks at the end on this line **'iedoc.getElementById("ListPortfolio").Value = "303591430"**:

---

```
Sub Strategic_Alpha_Monthly_Pivots_1_MASTER()

' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded

Dim ie As Object
Dim iedoc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmlSelect As Variant

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "http://analytics.financialexpress.net/login.aspx"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url


Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

' Input the userid and password
Set iedoc = ie.document
iedoc.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "xxxx"

' Click the "Search" button
iedoc.getElementById("btnAction").Click

While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend


iedoc.getElementById("ListPortfolio").Value = "303591430"
iedoc.getElementById("ListPortfolio").FireEvent ("onkeypress")

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to `Set iedoc = ie.document` again once the second page is loaded, otherwise it still points to the (now unloaded) first page

Comment: Thanks, i added that after the DoEvents Wend, but i still get a 'runtime error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set'

Comment: I see what went wrong, I need to add more of time delay eg application.wait to wait for the page to load before i reset the iedoc. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what went wrong, I need to add more of time delay eg application.wait to wait for the page to load before i reset the iedoc. thanks.